# Doubt regarding correct meditation technique

Tags: meditation

I have been doing meditation for around 20-30 minutes a day for 5 years. One thing I have noticed is I absorb my mind in both the awareness of my whole body (as in physical sensations such as pressure etc), and also the sensation of the breath in the whole body, I can reach a state where thoughts slow down lots, sometimes even stopping for a while. It’s a pleasant state, but I doubt if I am practicing correctly as I’m not sure if this was the method recommended by the Buddha.

Any advice would be appreciated.

All the best :)

Answer (score 2):

Buddhism has four main types of meditation practices. The first is **Metta**, which involves spreading kindness to oneself and the entire universe, avoiding anger, and wishing happiness, health, and even Nirvana to all beings. The second is **Anapanasati**, which helps you relax and focus your mind by concentrating on your breathing. The third type of meditation is **Buddhanussati/Dhammanussati/Sangha**, which involves thinking about the characteristics and specialties of Buddha, Dhamma, and Sangha to develop faith. Finally, **Vipassana** involves contemplating oneself and the universe as impermanent even souls, recognizing that everything has an end. This practice helps one avoid attachment to oneself or the world, view one's body parts as disgusting, and avoid bonding with them.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is similar to as taught by the Buddha, such as in [MN 118](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.118.than.html) & [MN 119](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.119.than.html).

This said, doing meditation for around 20-30 minutes a day will be like having a mental health check up. It won't progress meditation very far.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) How long should I meditate?

Comment: Thank you. I suppose my final comment was in response to another answer that referred to "jhanas". "Jhanas" cannot be reached practicing 30 minutes per day. As for your post, it sounds like you are doing OK if the mind is calmed & meditation feels "pleasant". Duration of meditation is up to you, your motives & your lifestyle.

Answer (score 0):

Its nice achievement.

1. If you master it you can get there quickly.
2. If you master staying there for long. Your mind and body will benefit like a deep sleep. i.e your mental and physical health will improve.
3. and as you rightly said you get joy. its a pure entertainment.

However There is danger there
It has nothing to do with buddha teaching,or nibbana.

You master the art of retreating when your mind is disturbed. Instead of doing observation of what arised and why it arisen, what is danger in what is arising, and how to escape from what is arising, and how long it will stay. You turn your attention away from this vipasana and turn toward the joy of breathing. So whatever has arisen will get suppressed. and stay with you always. and there is no more probability of arising something else too.

The joy that is arised due to seclusion from 6 sense thoughts. is also of anicca nature, its not in your control, it arises on its own, stay  and goes away. you should also  see danger, escape even in that joy.

You are also wasting time, since you are not doing vipassana of thought or that joy. people can stay in this state for days. and at the end  its nothing but entertainment. it is one kind of sensual pleasure only. as long as 6 Sense are there even this joy is sensual joy. A joy by seclusion of sensual pleasure is also sensual joy.

Comment: @Deepscarcity FYI, the question of whether the jhanas are necessary in the path to enlightenment had been covered in [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/is-jhana-required-for-awakening/1689#1689). The relationship between jhanas and insight (vipassana) had been discussed in this [answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/in-meditation-should-one-pursue-tranquility-first-prior-to-looking-for-insight/1334#1334) as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I’m not sure if this was the method recommended by the Buddha.

The method with the most detailed instructions recommended by the Buddha can be found in the Anapansati Sutta. There are many different interpretations of this Sutta among different authors, practitioners, monks, etc.

You would likely find it useful to read the Sutta. It may seem unclear though, and so after reading you can look up various authors interpretations of the sutta.

Some authors to choose from include Ajahn Brahm, Bhikkhu Analayo, Thanissaro Bhikkhu, and more (these author recommendations reflect my biases). You will note there are competing interpretations.

Another sutta is the Satipatthana Sutta, although it is not clear if this is really “meditation instructions.” Again, there are different interpretations of what this sutta entails.

Answer (score -1):

It is good to be able to enjoy the physical comfort and ease that arises during meditation. This is something that we can always fall back upon in difficult times. Moving forth, I would suggest that you look into the subject of your meditation object. While attending to the whole body (i.e. various parts of the body) can give rise to a pleasant state, there is too much flux and information, I feel, to allow the mind to develop absorption or one-pointed concentration (samadhi).

I would suggest you read some meditation techniques that specifically aimed to develop the jhanas. One freely available source is provided by [Venerable Pa-Auk Tawya Saydaw](http://buddhanet.net/pdf_file/know-see.pdf). Another meditation teacher that I find helpful is [Ajahn Brahm](https://bswa.org/teaching/basic-method-meditation-ajahn-brahm/). Though, the narratives and explanations can be quite a fair bit and personal but nonetheless helpful as references. May these sources provide you with even more joy and bliss in your journey in meditation. With Metta.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into them :)